# Print all the permutation of vector

Tags: algorithm, sorting, permutation

Let's design a clock. This clock has a format of (hour: miniutes). Lets use bit to represent it.

For example,

10: 15  is represented as 1010:1111.

### Question: given n as total number of bit that is 1, print all the possible clock time.  (eg, in the 10:15 example, n = 6, but I am asking you to print all the other possible configuration that also has six bit 1 ).

My attempt: I stored hours into a 5-element vector (max 24). And  minutes into a 6-element vector (max 60). And then I divide `n` into two numbers: `n = n-i, i`, for `i in the [0, n]`.

The former `n-i` represent number of 1s bit to turn on for hour vector, the latter `i` represents number of 1s bit to turn on for the minute vector. Then you can use `next_permutation` to get the next ordering of the vector (given that they have same number of 1s).

However, this is more like a brute force solution. I am wondering if you  guys have better algorithms in mind?

```
class Solution5 {
public:
    void print_clock (int n) {
        if (n == 0) {cout<<"0"<<endl; return;}
        vector<vector<int>> res;
        vector<int> hour (5, 0);
        vector<int> min (6, 0);
        for (int i=0; i< n; i++)
            rec_print(n - i, i, res, hour, min);
        cout<<endl<<"completed"<<endl;
    }

    void rec_print (int h, int m, vector<vector<int>> & res, vector<int>  hour, vector<int>  min) {
        if (h > 5 || m > 6) return;
        int z = hour.size() -1;
        while (h-- > 0) hour[z--] = 1;
        z = min.size() -1;
        //vector<int> hour = {0,0,1,1,1};
        while (m-- > 0) min[z--] = 1;
        //while(next_permutation(hour.begin(), hour.end()) )
        //    cout<<"he";

        while (get_vector(h, hour, 24) ) {
            vector<int> tmp = min;
            while (get_vector(m, tmp, 60)) {
                cout<<"hour : ";
                for (int i=0 ; i<hour.size(); i++)
                    cout<<hour[i];
                cout<<endl<<"miniutes : ";
                for (int i=0; i<min.size(); i++)
                    cout<<min[i];
                cout<<endl<<"---------------"<<endl;
                if(next_permutation(tmp.begin(), tmp.end()) == 0 ) break;
            }
            if (next_permutation(hour.begin(), hour.end())== 0) break;

        }
        //cout<<endl<<"completed"<<endl;
    }

bool get_vector (int n, vector<int> & tmp, int maxi) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = tmp.size() - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        sum += tmp[i] * pow(2,tmp.size() -1 - i);
        if (sum > maxi)
            return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```

Comment: What's wrong with using brute force? There are only 1440 minutes in 24 hours. (BTW, if your code works, this question should maybe be posted at codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: kk.. I am practicing for interview. They are always looking for a optimal solution. I think my current algorithm is OK. Let me try it on the codereview site

Answer (score 0):

Using a function that counts the number of ones in the binary representation of an integer (see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer)) you could iterate over the numbers 0 - 59, measure their number of ones (aka pop count or Hamming weight) and store them in a table like:

```
0: [0]  
1: [1,2,4,8,16,32]  
2: [3,5,6,9,10,12,17,18,20,24,33,34,36,40,48]  
...  
5: [31,47,55,59]
```

Then you iterate over the numbers 0 - 23, get their pop count c, and combine them with the numbers in the table row n-c, e.g.:

```
0: c=0, n-c=6 -> none  
1: c=1, n-c=5 -> 1:31, 1:47, 1:55, 1:59  
...  
23: c=4, n-c=2 -> 23:03, 23:05 ... 23:40, 23:48
```

This gives you the times in chronological order. I think the code will be both shorter and easier to understand than what you currently have.

---

Here's a quick code example (pardon my amateur C++). You can use [any popcount function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/how-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer), like the one built-in to the GNU compiler, or convert the integers to a bitset and use the [bitset::count](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/count/) function.

```cpp
int popcount(int i) {
    return __builtin_popcount(i); // GNU compiler built-in
}
int pop_count_times(int count) {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> minutes(6);
    for (int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
        minutes[popcount(m)].push_back(m);
    }
    for (int h = 0; h < 24; h++) {
        int ones = count - popcount(h);
        if (ones < 0 || ones > 5) continue;
        for (int m = 0; m < minutes[ones].size(); m++) {
            std::cout << h << ':' << minutes[ones][m] << ' ';
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to pad the numbers with leading zeros, you should add `cout.fill('0')` and `cout.width(2)` before printing each integer. In that case, the output for count=6 is:

```
01:31 01:47 01:55 01:59 02:31 02:47 02:55 02:59 03:15 03:23 03:27 03:29 03:30 03:39 03:43 03:45 03:46 03:51 03:53 03:54 03:57 03:58 04:31 04:47 04:55 04:59 05:15 05:23 05:27 05:29 05:30 05:39 05:43 05:45 05:46 05:51 05:53 05:54 05:57 05:58 06:15 06:23 06:27 06:29 06:30 06:39 06:43 06:45 06:46 06:51 06:53 06:54 06:57 06:58 07:07 07:11 07:13 07:14 07:19 07:21 07:22 07:25 07:26 07:28 07:35 07:37 07:38 07:41 07:42 07:44 07:49 07:50 07:52 07:56 08:31 08:47 08:55 08:59 09:15 09:23 09:27 09:29 09:30 09:39 09:43 09:45 09:46 09:51 09:53 09:54 09:57 09:58 10:15 10:23 10:27 10:29 10:30 10:39 10:43 10:45 10:46 10:51 10:53 10:54 10:57 10:58 11:07 11:11 11:13 11:14 11:19 11:21 11:22 11:25 11:26 11:28 11:35 11:37 11:38 11:41 11:42 11:44 11:49 11:50 11:52 11:56 12:15 12:23 12:27 12:29 12:30 12:39 12:43 12:45 12:46 12:51 12:53 12:54 12:57 12:58 13:07 13:11 13:13 13:14 13:19 13:21 13:22 13:25 13:26 13:28 13:35 13:37 13:38 13:41 13:42 13:44 13:49 13:50 13:52 13:56 14:07 14:11 14:13 14:14 14:19 14:21 14:22 14:25 14:26 14:28 14:35 14:37 14:38 14:41 14:42 14:44 14:49 14:50 14:52 14:56 15:03 15:05 15:06 15:09 15:10 15:12 15:17 15:18 15:20 15:24 15:33 15:34 15:36 15:40 15:48 16:31 16:47 16:55 16:59 17:15 17:23 17:27 17:29 17:30 17:39 17:43 17:45 17:46 17:51 17:53 17:54 17:57 17:58 18:15 18:23 18:27 18:29 18:30 18:39 18:43 18:45 18:46 18:51 18:53 18:54 18:57 18:58 19:07 19:11 19:13 19:14 19:19 19:21 19:22 19:25 19:26 19:28 19:35 19:37 19:38 19:41 19:42 19:44 19:49 19:50 19:52 19:56 20:15 20:23 20:27 20:29 20:30 20:39 20:43 20:45 20:46 20:51 20:53 20:54 20:57 20:58 21:07 21:11 21:13 21:14 21:19 21:21 21:22 21:25 21:26 21:28 21:35 21:37 21:38 21:41 21:42 21:44 21:49 21:50 21:52 21:56 22:07 22:11 22:13 22:14 22:19 22:21 22:22 22:25 22:26 22:28 22:35 22:37 22:38 22:41 22:42 22:44 22:49 22:50 22:52 22:56 23:03 23:05 23:06 23:09 23:10 23:12 23:17 23:18 23:20 23:24 23:33 23:34 23:36 23:40 23:48
```